# How should I change React input button width for mobile?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, webkit

I am trying to change the width of my input button. I can change it using chrome devtools when it's set to mobile, but once the React app is deployed and I check it on my phone, the width is unchanging. See screenshot below.

[image]

Thus far, I've changed my width size to all kinds of pixels and percentages and added these properties:

```
.TodoApp .button{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: use 'width:xxxpx/%' to set the width. Or you can use min-width.

Comment: can you show the element styles panel of this button when you do the DOM inspection. What i'm guessing is some CSS is overriding your custom styling. are you using any library or css base? if not, you can try with !important on width attribute to see if it overrules the styling.

Comment: @MuhammadAli I did min-width and max-width 10px and nothing changed.

Comment: @KevinMoeMyintMyat I don't know how to even check that stuff on mobile. Everything looks good when I set devtools to mobile view. https://www.abechoi.com/todo this is the app thus far.

Comment: then i guess you will need a CSS reset like normalize.css . looks like a browser specific CSS issues.